# Find 'matching' between words within one column and sentences in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataset that I wanted to join. These datasets have different lengths (125, 200, 1000)

```
One       Two                    Three
man     | man and woman         | there was a cat
nutella | lemon water           | pancakes
bread   | bread and nutella     | look at you
glass   | wine and water        | table
```

I would like to 'connect' each word in `One` to all the other rows in `Two` and `Three` which contain that word, something like this:

```
man : man and woman
nutella : bread and nutella
bread : bread and nutella
glass:
```

In case there were no words to connect (like `glass`), I would like to include all of them into a new word called `'Other'`.

Could you please tell me if it would be right to first search (using `str.contains` or `re.findall`) the word in the other two columns, then use `zip`?

My concern is, however, how to link each word in `One` with the others in `Two` and `Three`. I might do manually (adding, as search term, first `man`, then `nutella`, and so on) but I am wondering if I could do it automatically (for example transforming the column One into a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `findall` and `explode` with `melt` , here glass is drop , since it is not fund

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df.One)
s = df.melt('One')
s['New'] = s.value.str.findall(pat)
s = s.explode('New')[['value', 'New']].dropna()
s
Out[42]: 
               value      New
0      man and woman      man
2  bread and nutella    bread
2  bread and nutella  nutella
```

Put it into dict

```
d = dict(zip(s.New,s.value))
Out[46]: 
{'man': 'man and woman',
 'bread': 'bread and nutella',
 'nutella': 'bread and nutella'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask you about column Three? Why should I exclude it?

Comment: @Val check the update , I use melt first ~ , it will push two and three into one column ~ value

Comment: My fault! I did not update the page. Thank you so much @BEN_YO